# problem :globalization in C# using VS2005

Tags: c#

I want to globalize my application.
I have created a small form which asks the user their language.
I have a number of problems :

Problem 1:

In program.cs

```
new SplashScreen(_tempAL);
new LangForm(_lang);
Application.Run(new Form1(_tempAL, _lang));
```

I want the application not to call Form1 until the user clicks on OK in LangForm .
For more explaintion in LangForm :

```
    public LangForm(char _langChar)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ch = _langChar;
        this.TopMost = true;

        this.Show();

    }

    private void _btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _langStr = _cbLang.SelectedText;
        switch (_langStr)
        {
            case "English":
                _ch = 'E';
                this.Hide();
                break;
            case "Arabic":
                _ch = 'A';
                this.Hide();
                break;
            case "Frensh":
                _ch ='F';
                this.Hide();
                break;
        }
        _pressedOk = true;
    }

    private void _btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Now when I debug, the application calls LangForm and then Form1 so both forms are shown.
I want Form1 to wait until the user clicks on Ok in LangForm.

Problem 2:

When should I check on the language?  It's not allowed to check in "initializeComponent()"
so should I check after this function and then set controls location according to the language.

Problem 3:

Within application process I displays some message so before each "MessageBox.Show("");" I should check for the language or there is another way where I may set the language once.

Problem 4:

I have searched for interfaces for MessageBox as actually I want to change its layout. How can I find templates for MessageBox?

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the language selection form as a dialog.  Make your Program.cs file look like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  if (DialogResult.OK == new LangForm().ShowDialog()) {
    Application.Run(new Form1());
  }
}
```

Add this line to your _btnOK click handler:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Answer (score 1):

To block until a form has closed, use `.ShowDialog()` on the `LangForm`. I would then set the culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`) *between* this form closing and creating the new form. Having done this, anything from resx should load correctly.

For changing the layout of `MsgBox` (beyond the norm) you would have to write your own (it doesn't support this).

Something like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();

    // find the culture we want to use
    bool cont;
    string languageCode;
    using (LangForm lang = new LangForm()) {
        cont = lang.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
        languageCode = lang.LanguageCode; // "en-US", etc
    }
    if (!cont) return;

    // set the culture against the UI thread
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(languageCode);

    // show the main UI
    using (MainForm main = new MainForm()) {
        Application.Run(main);
    }
}
```

Note the use of the official culture codes will make it easier to use things like `CultureInfo`; if you want to use your own short-list, then use an enum, and write a method somewhere:

```
public static string GetCultureCode(MyCulture culture) {
    switch(culture) {
        case MyCulture.French: return "fr-FR";
        case MyCulture.English: return "en-GB";
        //...
        default: throw new NotSupportedException("Unexpected culture: " + culture);
    }
}
```